# Type declaration when calling function?

Tags: scala

When invoking bar function, it is possible to specify types as in function declaration. But what does it mean here?

Scala 2.11.6, ScalaIDE 4.1.0

```
def foo(a: Int, b: String, c: Object) = {
  //it compiles but what :Int means here?
  bar(a: Int, b: String, c: Object)
}

def bar(a: Int, b: String, c: Object) = {
  println(a, b, c)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not type annotations, but [*type ascriptions*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html)

> Ascription
>
> Type ascription is often confused with type annotation, as
>   the syntax in Scala is identical. The following are examples of
>   ascription:
>
> `Nil: List[String]`
>   `Set(values: _*)`
>   `"Daniel": AnyRef`
>
> Ascription is
>   basically just an up-cast performed at compile-time for the sake of
>   the type checker. Its use is not common, but it does happen on
>   occasion. The most often seen case of ascription is invoking a varargs
>   method with a single Seq parameter. This is done by ascribing the `_*`
>   type (as in the second example above).
>
> Ascription follows the type annotation conventions; a space follows
>   the colon.

It's specially useful for helping with type inference, when the compiler's help is not enough:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).foldRight(Nil)(_ :: _)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
              List(1,2,3).foldRight(Nil)(_ :: _)
                                           ^

scala> List(1,2,3).foldRight(Nil: List[Int])(_ :: _)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bar(a: Int, b: String, c: Object)
```

It simply means that you are explicitly telling the compiler that the argument `a` is of type `Int` (and so on). Normally if you dont, the compiler infers the type of the arguments while calling `bar`. By manually putting, you are telling it explicitly to infer it as `Int` and `String` and `Object`.

Note this is different from `asInstanceOf[]`. i.e. your call is not synonym to:

```
bar(a.asInstanceOf[Int], b.asInstanceOf[String], c.asInstanceOf[Object])
```

With `asInstanceOf`, you are forcing compiler to believe that it is the given type. i.e. the compiler no longer uses its head to prove `a` is an `Int`. With `bar(a: Int, b: String, c: Object)` you are helping it infer. Note this is a compiler error because it cannot convert `a` to `String`.

```
bar(a: String, b: Int, c: String)
```